# Mac temporarily freezes everytime I plug in/out my mouse (Macbook Pro M1 Pro)

Tags: macos, mouse, crash, apple-silicon, monterey

I'm on Monterey 12.2 with a Macbook M1 Pro.

Every time I plug a mouse in or out, my Mac freezes, and the scroll bars of all visible windows disappear then reappear avec 1-2 seconds.

Has anyone experienced that?
Any fix?

Comment: Could this be related to the “Show scroll bars: …” setting in the “Appearance” preference pane in System preferences? If it’s set to “Automatically based on mouse or trackpad”, then disconnecting the mouse would cause all your open UIs to update to hide their scroll bars. This could cause some lag, similar to the switchover from light to dark mode, when everything re-draws all at once

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks for your suggestion. You can ad that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could this be related to the “Show scroll bars: …” setting in the “Appearance” preference pane in System preferences?

If it’s set to “Automatically based on mouse or trackpad”, then disconnecting the mouse would cause all your open UIs to update to hide their scroll bars.

This could cause some lag, similar to the switchover from light to dark mode, when everything re-draws all at once.